# How to encrypt API tokens stored in MySQL and reverse them on request?

Tags: php, mysql, encryption

I am running a web application which generates API tokens to my clients to access the my website services. Services in my website are accessed via the URL the users integrate into their websites.

Below, URL example the clients integrate into their websites:

```
http://mywebsite.com/?secure_API_token=a1Os9Y0z
```

Tokens are generated in PHP and stored now as plain text in MySQL. My issue now if somebody hacks my database, then they can destroy the service. So, how can I encrypt/encode the tokens in database and reverse them back when clients request them to use? Because clients should be reminded with their tokens by email to access my application.

Any secure suggestion? And also to be quick on reversing and retrieving because the number of users is increasing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a dilemma: hash your tokens in your database so they are unrecoverable (and need to be reset if forgotten), or store them in plain text and allow database thieves to get access to real keys if the application is compromised.

Personally, I'd say that if someone hacks your app to get access to your whole database, it's rather game over anyway. At this point you would need to restore your application from version control, restore your database from the last daily backup, and reset all API tokens and user passwords. On that basis, you might say that hashing is the way to go.

That means that if a user forgets their token, you will be unable to provide it to them, either in a control panel or a remind-me feature. On that basis, a token reset feature would be necessary. I'd recommend here that you allow some grace on the old token, otherwise their service will stop working for the small time difference between their requesting a new token and configuring the new one in their application. Allowing the old one to work for half an hour, with an option to invalidate it earlier, would be fine.

That said, many API systems offer an SSL-protected control panel to retrieve API keys, which would imply they are stored in plain text. That may be fine if you can monitor usage to see if they are being used by an unauthorised user, and how important this is depends on what you are protecting.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification but I need to have a list of the plain-text API-keys and also hashing would be so slow and I read that it is not secure too. There is no algorithm to encrypt and reverse the API keys based on a another key stored in PHP?

Comment: @moderns: hashing in general _should_ be slow, although [some algorithms](http://uk1.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) allow you to specify the number of iterations (which directly affects speed). Don't prematurely optimise here - unless it creates a load that your server cannot bear, "slow" (in relative terms) is fine. Encryption won't help if your PHP application stores the decryption key: the hacker will just find the key on disk and decrypt everything easily.

Comment: thanks a lot. But if I store the decryption/decyryption key in a file outside the document root directory (/var/www), that wont be safe? Would you please recommend a PHP method to encode and decrypt the API key by using a key? If it is not secure, then would appreciate if you suggest me the best/quick Hash method to use! Thank you!

Comment: Still not secure. If someone breaks into your application they can read anything your application can read, since they have the same read/write permissions as the web server. So if your application can read something outside the docroot, so can the cracker. For hashing, the best available method is in my earlier link - use that. If you are on PHP <5.5 then there is a library available that works with 5.3.7+.

Comment: @moderns, why do you need a list of plain-text API keys?

Comment: @halfer: Many thanks I will go for hashing then and mark your answer as the solution :( Would you please suggest me a quick/secure hash method in PHP? I never used it.

Comment: I need them to email them to my clients when they lose the URL, so that would be a quick method instead of resetting which needs Control Panel which I don't use in my application.